# Help with some maths of a simple quantum field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

On youtube, Prof Susskind does some maths that looks quite dodgy and I was wondering if someone could help me with the logic behind it. He evaluates

$\int {\Psi^{\dagger}\Psi  }dx$

Where $\Psi$  is the operator representing the quantum field. He then goes through the following workings

$\int {\Psi^{\dagger}\Psi  }dx=\int dx \sum_{i}a^{+}_{i}\psi^{*}_{i} \sum_{j}a_{j}\psi_{j}$

$=\int dx \sum_{i,j}a^{+}_{i} a_{j}\psi^{*}_{i}\psi_{j}$

He then uses orthogonality of the wave functions $\int dx \psi^{*}_{i}\psi_{j}=\delta_{ij}$ to write

$\int {\Psi^{\dagger}\Psi  }dx = \sum_{i,j}a^{+}_{i} a_{j} \delta_{ij}=\sum_{i}a^{+}_{i} a_{i}$

But there are several things that look very wrong about these workings. First is that $a^{+}_{i}$ and $ a_{i}$ are treated as constants of the integration; how can this be? Secondly $a^{+}_{i}$ and $ a_{i}$ are operators and need to operate on something (what do they operate on?). Thirdly these operators are allowed to commute with the wave functions $\psi_{j}$. Why is this allowed?

Can anybody help me with this?

See 34:22 of the youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6vR825BR3c&index=7&list=PLcC5RwLpGl6eyNvVfAixR18_nDmsX9rh-

Comment: Link to the video?

Comment: See time 34:22 the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6vR825BR3c&index=7&list=PLcC5RwLpGl6eyNvVfAixR18_nDmsX9rh-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your questions are answered at 28:35 mark. I will just repeat what Susskind says here.

1. The creation operators $a^{\dagger}_{i}$ operate on a one-particle state creating $| i \rangle = a^{\dagger}_{i} | 0 \rangle$ from the vacuum $| 0 \rangle$. The state $| i \rangle$ is an energy eigenstate.
2. The $\psi_i (x) = \langle x | i \rangle$ are complex numbers. Therefore they should commute with $a_i$ and $a^{\dagger}_{i}$. The same is valid for $\psi^{*}_{i}$.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the video or having context for the problem, my assumption would be that in the second line, $a^\dagger_i$ operates on $\psi^*_i$ and $a_j$ operates on $\psi_j$, returning eigenvalues denoted $a^\dagger_i$ and $a_j$ respectively. It could certainly be considered an abuse of notation but such is not uncommon. These eigenvalues are then just constants and treated as such.

Comment: The video is below. The $a_{i}$ operators do not act on the wave functions $\psi_j$ . They act on some state |n1, n2, n3 ...>. See time 34:22 of the video below for where he does the maths:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6vR825BR3c&index=7&list=PLcC5RwLpGl6eyNvVfAixR18_nDmsX9rh-

Comment: At 18:50 he explains that these operators do indeed act on the wave functions, as the Fock state is composed of a sum of creation/annihilation operators acting on the wave functions.